# Discover who changed SQL Server service state

Tags: sql-server, security, audit

There's any way to find out who stopped\restarted\started the following services ?

- SQL Server Database Engine
- SQL Server Agent
- SQL Server Analysis Services

Thanks !

Comment: Have a look at this webpage : https://serverfault.com/questions/744734/log-username-of-who-restarts-a-service

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496632/is-it-possible-to-log-who-started-or-stopped-a-windows-service/496675

Moral of the story is event viewer/ system logs should show you

Comment: I don't think this is valid anymore... Just quickly tested it on my server and the "user" is "N/A" for the line in the "system" events that match the service stop and the service start

Comment: Bummer, your link looks promising though